# Skillet warps when hot -- Is it toast?

Tags: cookware

A griddle I've had recently appears to have adopted a strange behavior -- It's flat when cold, but after being on the stove for a little while it bows upward away from the burner. This makes doing much with it nearly impossible -- At this point is it pretty much toast?

Answer (score 4):

It is not toast if it gets flat afterwards. It is just too large for the burner on which you are using it.

The general rule is: if a skillet wraps with the center bending up, re-bend it (if possible - coated ones can crack the coating) and use on a larger burner. If it wraps center-down, rebend and use on a smaller burner.