# Can I use this reversable griddle on a glass top?

Tags: cookware

A local bargain store has a few of these for sale, and I'd like to pick one up because 1.) It's thick so it's unlikely to warp ([A problem I'm having with my current griddle](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/79221/skillet-warps-when-hot-is-it-toast)) 2.) It's flat without a handle so it will store pretty easy. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if I can use it on my stove because it only makes direct contact with the stove around the perimeter. Is it possible to use a skillet like this on a glasstop?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it would work better than you would guess.  Would still get all the radiant heat transfer.

Comment: Be careful with it not to scratch the glass.

Comment: Because of the perimeter  it would not sit on the surface of the cook top but hover above it with smooth side down only ribs would touch with the grill side down. It would be in efficient heat transfer but may work for low temp applications. Maybe for pancakes but not steaks. ?  try it. let us know. you can always use it as a heat-sink in the oven.